# problems with minim and processing

Tags: audio, processing, audio-recording, minim

trying to create a sound sampler that can play a recorded sample at different frequencies/rates and am using TickRate to change the rate of playback, similar to the TickRate example. when i run i get a NullPointerException here `player.patch(rateControl).patch(out);` but can't figure out why, any ideas why?

```java
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;

Minim minim;
AudioOutput out;
AudioSample sample1;

AudioInput in;
AudioRecorder recorder;
boolean recorded;
FilePlayer player;
TickRate rateControl;

void setup()
{

  size(512, 200, P3D);
  minim = new Minim(this);

  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 512);

  recorder = minim.createRecorder(in, "myrecording2.wav");
  rateControl = new TickRate(1.f);
  out = minim.getLineOut(Minim.STEREO, 512);
  player.patch(rateControl).patch(out);


  textFont(createFont("Arial", 12));

}

void draw()
{
  if ( recorder.isRecording() )
  {
    fill(255,255,255);
    text("Now recording, press the r key to stop recording.", 5, 310);
  }
  else if ( !recorded )
  {
    fill(255,255,255);
    text("Press the r key to start recording.", 5, 315);
  }
  else
  {
    fill(255,255,255);
    text("Press the q key to save the recording to disk as a sample.", 5, 315);

  }

    for(int i = 0; i < out.bufferSize() - 1; i++)
  {
    float x1 = map(i, 0, out.bufferSize(), 0, width);
    float x2 = map(i+1, 0, out.bufferSize(), 0, width);
    line(x1, 50 + out.left.get(i)*50, x2, 50 + out.left.get(i+1)*50);
    line(x1, 150 + out.right.get(i)*50, x2, 150 + out.right.get(i+1)*50);
  }

}

void keyReleased()
{
  if ( !recorded && key == 'r' ) 
  {
    if ( recorder.isRecording() ) 
    {
      recorder.endRecord();
      recorded = true;
    }
    else 
    {
      recorder.beginRecord();
    }
  }
  if ( recorded && key == 'q' )
  {
    player = new FilePlayer( recorder.save() );
    sample1 = minim.loadSample( "myrecording.wav" , 512 );
    if ( sample1 == null ) println("didn't get sample");
  }
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if ( key == 's' ) 
  {
    sample1.trigger();
  }

  else if ( key == 'd' )
  {
    rateControl.value.setLastValue(3.0f);
    sample1.trigger();
  }

}
```

Comment: What is `player` supposed to be? It looks like it's still null. I'm not familiar with this code though, so pardon my ignorance if that's a dumb question :)

Comment: @DerekHopper player is the name I've given to the FilePlayer, i thought it could be still null but couldn't figure out what to do. Honestly i'm not too familiar with it myself. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You only set `player` equal to something in the `keyReleased()` function. So when `setup()` is run, `player` still has the default `null` value.

Taking a step back, you should get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). When you get a `NullPointerException`, try printing out the value of every variable on that line. You'll find which one is `null`, and then you can figure out why.

Comment: Oh right okay. I'll try that now, thanks very much Kevin :)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That's helped get rid of the 'NullPointerException' . Now i just need to figure out how to get the tick rate working when playing the samples :)

Comment: @michaeldoherty Just out of curiosity, is there any reason you unaccepted this answer?